# Expected an identifier and instead saw ')' for loop jslint

Tags: javascript, for-loop, jslint

I have a for loop where I need to conditionally assign the value of variable I am using in for loop.

```
var b=null,a=top;

   try{

       for(a=top;a&&!a.tvcOI;)     
         if(a=a.opener)a=a.top;a&&(b=a.getOIFrame())   
       }
   }catch(d){}
```

OR

to be simplified for loop look like:

```
for(i=0;i<10;){

   if(condition matches){
      i++;
   }
   else {
     Do some other task;
   }
}
```

but jslint gives below error;
  Expected an identifier and instead saw ')'.

Comment: I would recommend using a `while` loop for this construct.

Comment: that's because you're ending the if condition here if(a=a.opener) what else are you expecting it to do?

Comment: Abdul I already tried if condition{} but it didn't help. 
Error comes for for loop:

Expected an identifier and instead saw ')'.

[INFO]        for(a=top;a&&!a.tvcOI;) {
[INFO]                              ^

Comment: There are a couple of errors which might be typos when you were posting here. The FOR loop is missing the opening brace. The IF condition is assigning `a=a.opener`. You also forgot the semicolon after `&&(b=a.getOIFrame())`. lint would complain about that.

Comment: @KamalYadav - if shxfee's answer helped you, don't forget to accept it by clicking the checkbox under the arrows to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect jsLint is complaining because you have left out the third expression for the FOR loop. try something like this instead.

```
for(a = top; a && !a.tvcOI; 0)
```